# Уникальные значения в поле таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как записать в поле mysql уникальные значения?
Если дано:
privet
privet
privet
... другие

Нужно записать (уникализировать добавлением дефиса и цифр)
privet
privet-1
privet-2
....

Подскажите как эффективнее реализовать на php?
Какие есть есть варианты?

Другой вариант: если поле таблицы перед вставкой будет вообще пустое.
(может все обрабатывать в массиве, а потом один раз записать в базу?)

Предположение искать каждый раз SELECTом и проверять.
но кажется будет очень много операций поиска... особенно на "больших данных" и это скажется на производительности

Comment: Попробуйте искать через REGEXP, а в конце прибавлять count записей, найденных с помощью regexp. Создайте триггер, который будет выполняться перед записью новой строки. Эту обработку можно сделать и на стороне PHP, тогда не поднадобится триггер, но последний обеспечит уникальность записи.

Comment: Почему вы хотите запихнуть всё в одно поле, а не создать еще одно?

Comment: Не понял про еще одно поле. Ну это одно поле с данными, просто как в моем примере могут встречаться одинаковые значения, а в поле нужны уникальные. Вот чтобы уникализировать нужно добавлять дефис и цифры.

Comment: @Андрей поле `id` с автоинкрементом. Вставляете записи без всяких проверок, а при чтении делаете конкатенацию искомого поля с полем `id` и с дефисом между ними. В чем причина того, что запись должна быть именно в одном поле?

Comment: Я понял вас, что потом id можно добавлять. Надо подумать над этим. Помимо моих "приветов" (privet) в этом поле есть/могут быть еще данные. Характеристики поля: varchar(255), NULL - нет. Просто описанный мною способ (с -1, -2, 3-) я уже видел, но не знаю как он реализован. Решил спросить.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример функции, которая может помочь:

```
function getUniqueValue($value)
{
    $value = trim($value);

    $i = 1;
    do {
        if (preg_match("/\-\d+$/i", $value)) {
            $value = preg_replace("/\-\d+$/i", sprintf("-%02d", $i++), $value, 1);
        } else {
            $value .= '-01';
        }
        $match = ... ;// здесь возвращается результат запроса с проверкой на наличие в базе такого поля
    } while ($match);

    return $value;
}
```